# lexical binding for a predefined global variable

Tags: lisp, elisp

Here is the snippet that confuses me:

```lisp
(setq lexical-binding t)
(defvar x 0)
    
(setq test (let ((x 1))
            (lambda () 
               x)))

(funcall test)
```

My understanding is that since `lexical-binding` is true, then the x of value 1 should cover the scope of `let`, which should include the `x` in the definition of `lambda`, as such, the test should return value of 1 instead of 0, but it turns out to return 0, which is the value of `x` by `defvar`.

Did I misunderstand anything?

**UPDATE**
Just for clarification, I would like to put my understanding here. Dynamical bounding means it only have one symbol and the value is popped in and out in a stack. As such, when the definition of `lambda` is done, the value used in let is popped out.
lexical/static bounding means the value is always been checked in the context of the lexical environment, so as long there is `let` before `lambda` definition, the value in `let` is used.
variable defined by `defvar` is always dynamically bound, as such, lexical-binding control here does not make any difference.

Comment: To expand upon Travis Sunderland's answer, `x` (which is always a dynamic variable, having been defined with `defvar`) has a dynamic binding of `1` while your lambda function is being *defined*, but the scope of that binding ends once that definition has happened, so `x` is no longer bound to `1` when you *call* that function.  The `let` form in this code is therefore redundant.

Comment: Also, `(setq lexical-binding t)` is not an approved way to use `lexical-binding`.  I'm not sure whether doing that has the intended effect at all.  You should only ever use the header-line comment to enable `lexical-binding` as a file-local variable in a library: `;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-`.  Note that you can use `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line` to insert that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html, even when `lexical-binding` is non-`nil`, special variables (like `x` since it was defined with `defvar`) are still dynamically bound.

Comment: I am still confused. actually no matter if lexical-binding is true or not, (funcall test) always return 0. shouldn't the latest value been used? and shouldn't the (x 1) be the latest value?

Comment: Are you familiar with how dynamic binding works? Since `x` is a special variable (because of the way it was defined - with `defvar`) it’s always dynamically bound. Your example code has no lexical bindings regardless of the value of `lexical-binding` because you’re only working with a special variable.

Comment: Maybe a clearer way to say it is that because `x` is a special variable, you’re not shadowing `x` in your `let`, you’re rebinding it, but only in the scope of that `let`. It’s still the same `x` even inside the `let`, so once the `let` scope ends and you call the function, `x` has been rebound back to its original value.